# Create a dataframe with all combinations

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe with 8 columns

Each cell can have 5 possible values

```
"strongly agree", "agree", "disagree", "strongly disagree" and NaN
```

I want to generate a dataframe with all the possibilities (permutations/combinations) so that I can use this dataframe for further processing.

Is it possible to generate this dataframe? In python or R ?

**To Summarize,**
A Dataframe with 8 columns and 5 combination of values.
5^8 rows of data should be there in the dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you want a cartesian product. You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

values = ["strongly agree", "agree", "disagree", "strongly disagree", pd.NA]

df = pd.DataFrame(product(values, repeat=8))
```

output:

```
                     0               1               2               3               4               5               6                  7
0       strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree     strongly agree
1       strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree              agree
2       strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree           disagree
3       strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly agree  strongly disagree
...
390620            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>     strongly agree
390621            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>              agree
390622            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>           disagree
390623            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>  strongly disagree
390624            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>               <NA>
```